# Does memory layout of a program depend on address binding technique?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, heap-memory, memory-layout, stack-memory

I have learned that with run-time address binding, the program can be allocated frames in the physical memory non-contiguously. Also, as described [here](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365071/does-a-program-use-logical-address-in-a-continuous-manner), every segment of the program in the logical address space is contiguous, but not all segments are placed together side-by-side. The text, data, BSS and heap segments are placed together, but the stack segment is not. In other words, there are pages between the heap and the stack segments (between the program break and stack top) in the logical address space that are not mapped to any frames in the physical address space, thus implying that the logical address space is non-contiguous in the case of run-time address binding.

[image]

But what about the memory layout in the case of compile-time or load-time binding ? Now that the logical address space in not an abstract address space but the actual physical address space, how is a program laid out in the physical memory ? More specifically, how is the stack segment placed in the physical address space of a program ? Is it placed together with the rest of the segments or separately just as in the case of run-time binding ?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your quesitons, I first have to explain a bit about `stack` and `heap` allocation in modern operating systems.

Stack as the name suggest is the continues memory allocation, where cpu uses `push` and `pop` commands to add/remove data from top of the stack. I assume that you already know how stack works. process stores -  *return address*, *function arguments* and *local variables* over stack. Every time a function is called, more data is pushed (it could ultimately lead to stack overflow is no data is popped ever - infinite recursion?). Stack size is fixed for a program when it is loaded in the memory. Most of the programming language lets you decide stack size during compilation. If not, they will decide a default. On Linux, maximum stack size(hard limit) is limited by `ulimit`. You can check and set the size by `ulimit -s`.

Heap space however, has no upper limit in *nix systems(depends, confirm it using `ulimit -v`), every program starts with a default/set amount of heap and can increase as much needed. Heap space in a process is actually two linked lists, `free` and `used` blocks. Whenever memory allocation is required from heap, one or more free blocks are combined to form a bigger block and allocated to the used list as a single block. Freeing up means removing a block from the used list to the free list. After Freeing the blocks, heap can have external fragmentation. Now if the the number of free blocks can't contain the whole data, process will request more memory from the OS, Generally the newer blocks are allocated from a higher address. Thus we show upward direction diagram for heap growth. I rephrase - **Heap does not allocate memory continuously in a higher direction**.

Now to answer your questions.

> With compile-time or load-time address binding, how are the stack and
>   the heap segments placed in the physical address space of a program ?

Fixed stack is allocated at compile time, with some heap memory. How are placed have been explained above.

> Is the space between the heap and the stack reserved for the program
>   or is it available for the OS to be used for other programs ?

Yes it is reserved for the program. Process however can request more memory to add free blocks in its heap. It is different than sharing it's own heap.

*Note: There are lots of topic which can be covered here as the question is broad. Some of them are - garbage collection, block selection, shared memory etc. I will soon add the references here.*

References:-

- [Memory Management in JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html#wp1086343)
- [Stack vs Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213360/1699956)
- [Heap memory allocation strategies](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~fischer/cs536.s08/lectures/Lecture31.4up.pdf)